# Flex 4.6 Scroller - Is it possible to disable scrolling temporarily through Actionscript?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flash-builder, flex4.6

I am trying to make a mobile app that would allow a drag and drop of certain elements using startDrag() and stopDrag().  These elements are enclosed inside of a spark scroller.  I would like to disable the scroller when someone is interacting with the draggable objects, but can't seem to get the scroller to not respond.

Here are the things I have tried.

```
protected function draggableObjectOnMouseBegin(e:MouseEvent):void {
    scrollerObject.enabled = false;
    scrollerObject.mouseEnabled = false;
    scrollerObject.mouseFocusEnabled = false;
    draggableObject.setElementIndex(e.currentTarget as IVisualElement, dragabbleObjectGroup.numElements-1);
    e.currentTarget.startDrag();
}
```

But the scroller will not stop scrolling.  Am I missing something or is there no wat to temporarily stop a scrollers ability to scroll to allow for drag and drop type operations on objects enclosed in a scroller.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I just trying to do exactly this this myself and I think I have a working answer.

What you need to do is set the `verticalScrollPolicy` (and/or horizontal). You do this via the setStyle method:

```
scrollerObject.setStyle('verticalScrollPolicy', ScrollPolicy.OFF);
```

Obviously to re-enable scrolling just set the policy back to ON.